# iOS Parse ban a user

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want to ban a user in my app using Parse framework but it don't work.

I have a column in my user database to ban users. I set the variable manually (on parse.com and not in my app).

[image]

I check that value in AppDelegate :

```
// Check if user is connected
    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

    if currentUser != nil {
        // if user is connected, check if he is ban

        let isBan = currentUser!.objectForKey("isBan") as! Bool
        print("Is user ban ? : \(isBan)")
        if isBan == true {
            PFUser.logOutInBackground()
        }
```

Problem ! I set the variable "isBan" to TRUE but the print output show the variable is still FALSE...
What am I missing ? thanks

**EDIT : SOLVED**

I have to refresh the user before checking the boolean isBan :

```
currentUser!.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock // refresh the user asynchronously
```

Comment: try using `.boolForKey("isBan")` this will return a bool instead of any object.

Comment: there is no member .boolForKey

Answer (score 1):

Try with ***valueForObject***

```
if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {
    // if user is connected, check if he is ban
    let isBan = currentUser.valueForKey("isBan") as! Bool //supposed isBan allways exist in user table
    print("Is user ban ? : \(isBan)")
    if isBan {
        PFUser.logOutInBackground()
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are the CurrentUser with true isBan value in table? I see 2 rows. Check printing username

Comment: just checked, yes i'm the currentUser with true ban. only 2 users in my table

Comment: mmm ok, my last suggest, print or breakpoint currentUser to see all json value.. and check ban value... maybe you are anonymous user

Comment: did it, the user is ok :  username = "q@q.q"; isBan = 0;

Comment: solved, I found I need to refresh the user to update the value if I changed it manually. Thanks for help